# Select multiple columns from a spark data frame more concisely

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

So I have the following piece of code that works:

```
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
case class Person(name: String, age: Int, gender: String)
val peopleRDD: RDD[Person] = sc.parallelize(Seq(Person("Jack Ryan", 10, "M"), 
                                              Person("Remi Lekan", 11, "M"), 
                                              Person("Lola Adeyemi", 8, "F")))
val people = peopleRDD.toDS
val delim="^"
def mySimpleHashModel(params: Map[String, Any])={params("name") +  delim +
                               params("age").toString() + delim + params("gender")}
val simpleHashUdf = udf { (name: String, age: Int, gender: String) => 
               mySimpleHashModel(Map("name"->name, "age"->age, "gender"->gender))}
val resDf= people.withColumn("data",
                           simpleHashUdf(col("name"),col("age"), col("gender")))
resDf.show()
```

This code works, but I'm fairly new to Scala Spark so I'm wondering how to make this code a bit more concise.

1. Is there a more concise way to specify the arguments to `simpleHashUDf` instead of listing the individual columns as in `simpleHashUdf(col("name"),col("age"), col("gender"))` ?
2. Is there more concise way to create the Map rather than specifying each element as in `mySimpleHashModel(Map("name"->name, "age"->age, "gender"->gender)` ?

I'm asking this because the actual case I will work on actually has much more than 2 columns like in this example.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you have a list of column names as strings in a variable `val colnames`. I'd still suggest to use the `concat` spark function as the others have suggested, just with a little change:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

df.withColumn("data", concat(colnames.map(x => col(x)): _*))
```

The `: _*` extracts each element from the list as a parameter into the `concat` function.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Spark has `concat` function.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.withColumn("data", concat(col("name"), col("age")))
```

Comment: Sorry I used concat as an example. It seems like it has obscured the real question which is how could I specify the columns from a list without having to specify each one individually. I have edited the question.

Comment: Yes ,there is a method. You can use `df.coluns` or `df.schema.fields` which you can use to create map. If I understand question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I would also suggest using built-in `concat` function. I'm not quite sure why you want to work with a `Map` in this case. But if you wish, you could rewrite our code like this:

```
val concatUdf = udf { (row:Row) =>
  // creates map from all fields
  concatModel(row.getValuesMap[Any](row.schema.fieldNames))}

val resDf= people.withColumn("data",
  concatUdf(struct("*")) // select all fields of dataframe
)
```

Comment: Sorry I used concat as an example. It seems like it has obscured the real question which is how could I specify the columns from a list without having to specify each one individually. I have edited the question.